# insert div into a menu item before the link and more

Tags: menus

I make a web page in Wordpress using a certain theme. Now, this theme has an expected markup for the menus:

```
<ul id=”primary-navigation-main”>
    <li>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>Page 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>Page 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On the mobile menu the wishes are slightly different. In the company they want some transition while pressing on the menu item. Something that I solved at another (hardcoded) menu like that:

```
<ul id=”primary-navigation-main”>
    <li>
        <div class=”transition-div”></div>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>
            <p>Page 1</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class=”transition-div”></div>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>
            <p>Page 2</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class=”transition-div”></div>
        <a href=”https://example.com/page1”>
            <p>Page 3</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/igorbeuermann/8wraLv37/1/).

I don’t know if this is the best solution for this transition but it works.

So, I would like to add `<div>` into `<li>` before `<a>` and in the `<a>` I would like to add `<p>`. I was fiddling with `wp_nav_menu` and `wp_nav_menu_items` but I wasn’t successful. Do I need to register `<ul>` or something else? Also it seems I will have to use a Walker class but I don't know how.

Could anybody help me or simply tell me it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I overslept and came to a completely different solution with the same visual outcome. It simply doesn't use additional `div` in the `li` elements and `p` elements in the `a` element. The [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/igorbeuermann/6Lwpeqvd/53/) shows the solution thanks to the [Keith J. Grant's idea](https://keithjgrant.com/posts/2017/07/transitioning-gradients/) I encountered. So instead of Wordpress I honed a bit my CSS skills.

But actually, the question remains: how to insert an arbitrary markup into a certain existing menu (in my case the primary menu of the chosen theme). That is into each menu item `li` and then into each link `a`, preserving the menu's URLs.